# Set class name correctly in python

Tags: python, class

i am looking for a way to set class name which belongs to without explicitly set. Adding a name variable is not necessary, i just want to reach the correct name of class.

Thanks

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, obj={}, num=0):
        self.name= type(self).__name__
        self.obj = obj
        self.num = num

    def add_to_db(self):
        pass


class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def method1(self):
        print("b method")

a=B()
print(a.name)
```

Below code returns "B", i want it to be "A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you **always** expect an instance to return the name of its superclass (unless it's `object` then it will report its own name), you can achieve this by querying hierarchy in the MRO (Method Resolution Order) list.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        mro = type(self).mro()
        print(mro)
        self.name = mro[0].__name__ if len(mro) == 2 else mro[1].__name__

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

assert a.name == 'A', a.name
assert b.name == 'A', b.name
assert c.name == 'B', c.name
```

**HERE BE DRAGONS**

A more 'destructive' way to achieve this can be using a meta-class but this will override `__name__` and may screw up `isinstance` checks. This will not create `.name` on instances but will override `__name__` on the class.

```py
class BaseClassNameMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        name = bases[0].__name__ if bases else name
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)

class A(metaclass=BaseClassNameMeta):
    pass

class B(A, metaclass=BaseClassNameMeta):
    pass


a = A()
b = B()

assert type(a).__name__ == 'A'
assert type(b).__name__ == 'A'
```

Comment: What is the point of defining `__init__` with the body `super().__init__()` in subclasses?

Comment: @S.B In this very contrived and stripped down example, there isn't.